# Moving a section heading and first line back a page in overleaf

Tags: sectioning, thesis, subsection

[image]

Hello, i would like to move the section 2.1.2 back to the space on page 3, just the title, first sentence and equation. It fit before and I haven't changed anything in the top section to make it move down. I just refreshed.

Comment: Please give us a little bit more context and maybe read this article https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . Give us your MWE (minimal working example). Also, why do you want to move the headline back up top. The beauty of TeX/LaTeX is that you dont have to worry about formatting, it will do it for you.

Comment: Off-topic: Please delete the blank line between `It can be stated as:` and `\begin{equation}`. Why? Because it's poor typographic practice to force a paragraph break immediately before a display-math group (such as an `equation` environment).

Comment: Please post actual code, *not* a screenshot of code.

Comment: Hello, sorry it seems to have fixed itself. thank you! I will look at the article for next time, and will add code instead of a screenshot too. I wanted to move it up as I have a page limit for my dissertation and when it moved down it added an extra page at the end of the section, with only a couple of sentences.